# How to find the right Linux Distribution?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions

I am going to be getingt a new laptop soon. I have been using Windows till now but have had some experience with Linux too. Now I want to completely shift towards Linux and for that purpose I was Googling to find out which distro of Linux to go with. I found Fuduntu, BackTrack, CentOS and Fedora interesting. In Fuduntu, they say, it is 30% more efficient on battery. I have used BackTrack, and I found that it provides hell lot of tools for hacking and other tasks.

I am confused as to which OS should I install. I am looking for guidance as to where I should look to learn more about the different distributions of Linux that are out there. Where should I be looking?

Comment: \*ahem\* http://biebian.sourceforge.net/

Comment: thats great I must say..:)

Comment: No-one can really decide what's best for you. This is a Q & A site, not a forum, so if you have a specific issue with any distro feel free to ask.

Comment: I am a Fedora user and it really is the best distro for me, but I would not recommend it for beginners. Ubuntu is the easiest choice, if you want a bit more of a challenge try Debian, openSUSE or Mageia. Backtrack and CentOS are hardly desktop distros.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. Your question tells me you want to learn. I'd start with Ubuntu (or a derivative thereof).

> Now I want to completely shift towards Linux

oh but before you commit yourself thoroughly to Unix do read http://web.mit.edu/~simsong/www/ugh.pdf for some light hearted fun.